# Window is not defined errors in React and Next.js

Tags: reactjs, windows, next.js, undefined, navbar

I'm using React Hooks and NextJS. I'm about to create a Navbar along with its functionality. But, by the time I'm going to refresh my page, this error is shown up.

Back when I was using this code on my React Project, it worked perfectly fine.

Can somebody help me where did it go wrong?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfXd4.png)

I also attach my full code here: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIii0.png)

Comment: nextjs doesn't let you directly manipulate the DOM.Avoid using vanilla javascript when you are using a framework

Comment: nex.js is run both on front end (in the browser) and on the server. So when it runs on server, `window` object is not defined. Also, probably in your case, a CSS media query will be more than enough. as Emin Pointed out

Answer (score 1):

As Shivam mentioned in comment, you cannot use window object in server.
you can do following

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      window.addEventListener("resize", showButton)
    }
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", showButton)
  }, [showButton)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

`window.addEventListener('resize', function() { console.log('addEventListener - resize'); }, true);`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: How does this attempt to answer the question?